# How can I make a Bootstrap 4 column follow the scroll of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with two columns - one to the left (with a jar), and another to the right (with buttons).

https://codepen.io/OakTreePedro/full/NEEVxr

When the screen is large, I have them side by side, and to see all of the right columns' contents, I have to scroll down. When I do so, I want the contents on the left column to follow that scroll, and that isn't currently happening.

**Basically, when trying to select a filter from the bottom of the right column, I want the jar on the left column to accompany the scroll-down.**

I've already tried a number of things:

- I've tried to use media-queries - if the screen's `min-width` was `992px`, I would apply a `position: fixed` or a `position: sticky` to the left column;
- I've tried using JavaScript - on `window.resize()`, if the `innerWidth` was `>= 992`, I would apply `position: fixed` or `position: sticky` to the left column's `style`, or `classList.add(position-fixed)`/`classList.add(position-sticky)`/`classList.add(sticky-top)`;
- I'm currently trying to use `stickyfill` with the aforementioned solution to achieve my goal but to no avail.

Here's my code:

https://codepen.io/OakTreePedro/pen/WLyBqp

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 animated slideInLeft" id="jar-section">
```

CSS:

```
.sticky-jar-section {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 15px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var jar_section = document.getElementById("jar-section");

window.onResize = function() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 992) {
        jar_section.classList.add("sticky-jar-section");
        Stickyfill.add(jar_section);
    } else {
        jar_section.classList.remove("sticky-jar-section");
        Stickyfill.remove(jar_section);
    }
};
```

I expect the left column to follow the scroll, like in this example (not mine):

https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/pJRRKW

EDIT because I've made a mistake when copying the code here and forgot the double-quotes around a class.

Comment: You need to call the reference, not execute the function for `window.onResize`. In any case it's better to use `window.addEventListener('resize', function);`

Comment: Hey @IslamElshobokshy, I made a function called `windowResize()` and then added the event listener for the resize, making a callback to the `windowResize()` function. Still, I didn't get my expected result. What else do you suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be sufficient to add:

```
#jar {
  padding: 0em 0em 0.5em 0em;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;

}
```

That will behave as `relative element` when no scroll is present, when scroll is present it will behave as `sticky element`, **scrolling only when both columns have reached the end of the document**.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMrJae

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably didn't understand what you said (even after multiple readings, my fault though) but it doesn't behave like I expected it to when I scroll down.

Comment: Maybe it's my fault, what's the final result you're expecting ?

Comment: Basically, when I scroll down to select a filter from the column on the right, I want the jar on the column to the left to follow the scroll. I may have not made this clear on my original post, so I'll edit it! Thanks for the patience!

Comment: Sorry, this is still not clear. The default box model work as expected: as I scroll, all elements follow the scroll, no tricks need to be applied.

Comment: My mistake, your code does indeed work! But it only moves the "My EmoJar" title and the jar itself - the counter just beneath the jar doesn't keep up with the movement of the jar.

I've tried to apply your code to the whole column with the `id=jar-section`, as opposed to what you did, which was applied only to the jar - in that instance, your code does not work :/ How do I make your code work for the entire column, instead of just the jar?

Many thanks! And sorry for my mistake!

Comment: You have to enclose both elements in the same container (I.E: <div />) and then apply the above CSS to the container

Comment: I approve of this answer tho, +1.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini, you're absolutely right :) ! I've put everything I wanted to move inside one single <div /> (it just couldn't be the col with id="jar-section" itself, as I ran into some trouble if I did), and to it I applied the CSS you provided, thus achieving my end goal.

I've accepted your answer. Thank you (and everybody else, of course!)!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `div` putting inside the part of code creating the element, and using `sticky` on that `div` :

```
<div id="stay">
    <!-- Jar -->
    <div class="text-center" id="jar">
        <!-- Jar's name -->
        <h4>My EmoJar</h4>

        <!-- The jar itself, generated by D3.js -->
    </div>

    <!-- Jar's content counter (currently being shown vs. total) -->
    <div class="text-center">
        <h4><i class="fa fa-chevron-left jar-content-counter-icons"></i><span id="jar-content-counter-text"></span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right jar-content-counter-icons"></i></h4>
</div>
```

With `sticky` as suggested :

```
#stay {
  padding: 0em 0em 0.5em 0em;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/elshobokshy/pen/ebKwvL

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to remove the JavaScript code and to only use CSS with one media query. Extending Islam Elshobokshy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54095698) I would create a div inside the `#jar-section` div, and give the `sticky` attribute to the inner div with a media query.

**Jar Section:**

```
<!-- Jar section -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 animated slideInLeft" id="jar-section">
    <div id="sticky-container">
        <!-- Jar -->
        <div class="text-center" id="jar">
            <!-- Jar's name -->
            <h4>My EmoJar</h4>
            <!-- The jar itself, generated by D3.js -->
        </div>
        <!-- Jar's content counter (currently being shown vs. total) -->
        <div class="text-center" id="jar-2">
            <h4><i class="fa fa-chevron-left jar-content-counter-icons"></i><span id="jar-content-counter-text"></span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right jar-content-counter-icons"></i></h4>
        </div>
        <hr width="50%">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#jar-section {
    padding: 0; /* this is only to overwrite the existing padding */
}
#sticky-container{
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 1em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    #sticky-container{
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 1em;
        padding-top:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that's what I did following @MosèRaguzzini's suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: It wasn't me, in case you're wondering. All help is appreciated!