# how to make bootstrap column sticky while scrolling

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, scroll

I want to create a faq page like [Twitter's FAQ](https://help.twitter.com/en/new-user-faq). The left column stays on that position even though the user keep scrolling.

So far here's what I made but it doesn't work.

```
    <template>
      <div>header here</div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div style="position: sticky;">
              1 of 2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            2 of 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090731/how-can-i-make-a-bootstrap-4-column-follow-the-scroll-of-the-page), we should add `sticky` property, but it doesn't work.

edit: I think it's because the two columns have the same height, so adding `sticky` property does not work. Any solutions on how to make the column height fit to the content only?

Any solution? Thank you!!

Comment: can you tell me the version of bootstrap that you are using?

Comment: I think it's `v 4.5.2` @MuhammadTahseenurRehman

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707076/how-does-the-position-sticky-property-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position **Sticky** is not working on col-sm-4 because its parent class **`row`** has `display:flex` property. if you change

> `display:flex`

to

> `display:block`

then position **Sticky** property will work but it will change your design

Comment: I've tried it and it does not work. I've also edited my question, maybe you might want to take a look. Thanks btw!

Comment: I edited the answer. I hope this will work for you

Comment: "but it will change your design" so it's not an answer then :))